# admob ads disappearing and delay

Tags: android, admob

hi I am new in admob ads and I just start using it, I created a simple ad and it worked fine but when I exits the app and run it again the ad disappeared and stopped showing, and then I tried again after closing and opening the app the ad appeared after 60 seconds, any one know the reason of this.

Comment: review logs. usually logs are updated with reason of failure

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that when no ad was showing there was no ad available for your app at that point in time. You may find that while your app is still making few requests that it doesn't always get an ad response.